# Android passing R.layout.extra_layout to View.inflate dynamically

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

I'm trying to programmatically pass the id of a layout.xml file to the View.inflate method but am not sure how I could go about that. I have a test bit of code that I'm tring to get working and, as you'll see I've tried passing this in as a String but that doesn't work.

Any ideas? My thanks.

```
LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);    
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        String boxToInflate="R.layout.box"+Integer.toString(i);
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(MainActivity.this, boxToInflate, null);
        main.addView(ll);
}
```

Edit: A few minutes later.

I think I may be making some progress with this test code:

```
    // Get outer relative layout
    LinearLayout main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // String boxToInflate="R.layout.box"+Integer.toString(i);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("box" + i, "id",
                getPackageName());
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(MainActivity.this,
                resID, null);
        main.addView(ll);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int layoutId = getResources().getIdentifier("box"+i, "layout", getPackageName());
```

It also works for other things like drawables ("drawable" instead of "layout"), etc. Just replace the second parameter.

EDIT : Saw your edit, just replace "id" with "layout" and you're good.

Comment: Thanks Stephane, appreciate that - I'd spotted id needed to be changed to layout.